# Clear ManyToMany via cascaded OneToOne remove

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm facing problems in a Hibernate project where I try to remove a OneToOne relation which still has entries in a ManyToMany relation.

Entities:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employeeId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private AppUser appUser;
    
    // some more basic fields

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
    @NotNull
    private Employee employeeId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "AppUserPermission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appUserId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permissionId"))
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
    
    // some more basic fields
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Permission implements Serializable {

    @Id
    Long id;
    
    // some more basic fields
}
```

DB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AppUser
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    employeeId bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_AppUser PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uq_AppUser_employeeId UNIQUE (employeeId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AppUser_employeeId FOREIGN KEY (employeeId)
        REFERENCES Employee (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Permission
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Permission PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AppUserPermission
(
    appUserId bigint NOT NULL,
    permissionId bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_AppUserPermission PRIMARY KEY (appUserId, permissionId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AppUserPermission_appUserId FOREIGN KEY (appUserId)
        REFERENCES AppUser (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_UserPermission_permissionId FOREIGN KEY (permissionId)
        REFERENCES Permission (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

When I now try to remove the User-entry from an Employee, where the User has no Permission, it works as expected - User is deleted from the DB:

```java
Employee employee = session.find(Employee.class, employeeId);

// user has no permission(s)
Assert.assertTrue(employee.getAppUser().getPermissions().isEmpty());

employee.setAppUser(null);
session.update(employee);
session.flush();
```

It's also possible to remove the Permissions via Employee - the entry in the DB's jointable got removed, the permission still is available:

```java
Employee employee = session.find(Employee.class, employeeId);

// user has permission(s)
Assert.assertFalse(employee.getAppUser().getPermissions().isEmpty());

employee.getAppUser().getPermissions().clear();
session.update(employee);
session.flush();

// this would also work now, but I wan't prevent two updates if possible
employee.setAppUser(null);
session.update(employee);
session.flush();
```

But as stated above, I'd like to do it in one update:

```java
Employee employee = session.find(Employee.class, employeeId);

// user has permission(s)
Assert.assertFalse(employee.getAppUser().getPermissions().isEmpty());

employee.setAppUser(null);
session.update(employee);
session.flush();
```

With the above code snippet, the following exception occurs:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "appuser" violates foreign key constraint "fk_appuserpermission_appuserid" on table "appuserpermission"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1825727638) is still referenced from table "appuserpermission".
  Ort: Datei: ri_triggers.c, Routine: ri_ReportViolation, Zeile: 2609.
  Server SQLState: 23503
```

JPA executes:

```
/* delete test.hibernate.AppUser */ delete 
    from
        appuser 
    where
        "id"=?
```

But what I expect is something like that:

```
DELETE FROM AppUserPermission WHERE appUserId = ? AND permissionId = ?;

DELETE FROM AppUser WHERE id = ?;
```

Does someone have an idea how to solve?

I know it would work if I change the on-delete cascade option from restrict to cascade on the table AppUserPermission, but I'm wondering if Hibernate is able to handle it without that. Since now, JPA handled all cascaded deletions in proper order, also if the DB's option is restrict.

***EDIT***:
The permission(s) belonging to the AppUser should not be deleted - just the entry in the ManyToMany-jointable.

Any hints appreciated :)

Comment: To understand your question better, you do not want to use that line and permissions will be deleted from the table, correct?
**`employee.getAppUser().getPermissions().clear();`**

Comment: Actually, I'm just trying to remove the AppUser-entry from the Employee-entry with an update via Employee. But since the User has Permissions, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in the `AppUser` class?

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "AppUserPermission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appUserId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permissionId"))
private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
```

Since you use specify cascade `CascadeType.ALL` when `AppUser` entry is deleted, associated permissions also should be deleted automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I don't wan't the permissions to be deleted. I still tried that and it doesn't work. Instead of having JPA removing the entry from AppUserPermission, it tries to delete the permission (which is still referenced in AppUserPermission).

Answer (score 0):

Applicable solution found by a colleague:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_AppUserPermission_appUserId FOREIGN KEY (appUserId)
    REFERENCES AppUser (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
```

It was more a DB/postgresql topic, but it solves the problem. Hibernate will execute both delete statements - for the AppUser and AppUserPermission, but in the "wrong" order. Making the foreign key deferrable will validate the state at the end of the transaction. Deferrable is not applicable on RESTRICT - therefore it must be NO ACTION (which is mostly the same but allows having foreign keys deferrable).